# how to resolve socket-io send connect request infinitely?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, websocket, socket.io

I'm new in socket-io. socket-io working fine but keep sending connect request infinitely to server.
Here is my client ts :

```
private url = environment.socketServer;
constructor() {  this.socket = io(this.url) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason for a socket.io  client to try to connect over and over is if the socket.io version on the server and client are not compatible.  The client connects, the server finds the version is incompatible and drops the connection and the client then tries to connect again, over and over.

Other possible issues:

1. Server infrastructure (such as load balancers, proxies, firewalls, etc...) are not properly configured to allow webSocket connections.
2. You're trying to connect to a cluster, but it isn't configured for sticky connections that will "bind" a socket.io client to the same server.
3. You're confused about how a socket.io connection starts.  It is normal for the client to start with a couple web connections in a row (polling) until it realizes that both sides support a webSocket and then socket.io switches over to webSocket.

Comment: socket.io  server and client version compatible. This problem happen ,while socket running on production environment. I'm using aws production.

Comment: @RahulDapke - Then, it's very likely that your AWS configuration is not set up properly for webSocket connections (load balancer, firewall, proxy, web server settings, etc...).  For the type of AWS product/account you have, you should be able to find explicit instructions for how to configure it for webSocket access.

Comment: I checked all configuration settings. Re-deployed application still keep connect request to server